# Wrapping inline nested lists with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering if its possible to create the following behavior using flexbox and wrapping.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.list {
  display: inline;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: light-gray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">asfasfasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
      <div class="item">asfff asfasasfasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">trailing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXqgag?editors=1100

The above has two `inline` containers with items, one nested in the other, where the outer item aligns next to the inner items, "crossing" the boundary of the inner container.

I'd like to use flexbox with the same setup for some of the other niceties of flexbox alignment options. Assuming that the nested list is a hard requirement, is there away to use flex, or `inline-flex` to achieve the same behavior of the "Trailing" item. My attempts, have always left the trailing item break on its own line, it seems that `inline-flex` is more akin to `inline-block`;.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout works because the containers are `display: inline`. This allows the elements to align side-by-side even after wrapping.

Your layout would *not* work if the containers were `display: inline-block`, as a box would wrap the nested `.list` element, forcing the "trailing" element to the next line.

`display: inline-flex` is similar to `display: inline-block`. The "trailing" element doesn't intrude into its sibling's block box and exists in its own box, which could be adjacent or below its sibling, depending on the `display` value of their parent.

Flex alignment can, however, be used on the content of each `.item`.

```css
html { font-size: 10px; }

body {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.list {
  display: inline;
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;         /* adjusted */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;  /* corrected; light-gray not a valid color */
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">asfasfasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
      <div class="item">asfff asfasasfasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
      <div class="item">afasf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">trailing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMBNXm?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't quite answer the question. I realize that why layout works with inline and why it won't work with inline-block, the question is whether there is some way to recreate the behavior with flexbox on the lists. inline-flex on the items doesn't help me.

Comment: I was explaining why it's not possible. The `inline-flex` on the items was just a side note.

Comment: appreciated, tho you might want to lead with "There isn't a way to do what you are asking" as it is I read the answer as you re-explaining the question to me, and why the two cases are different.

Comment: I would have done that if I was certain about what you were asking. You just mentioned "flexbox alignment options", but didn't specify exactly what part of the layout, which is why I mentioned flex properties would work on the items. Basically, I wasn't entirely sure what you were asking.